# How to fetch the status of Execute pipeline activity and pass it to stored procedure activity in ADF

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have 2 activities in my ADF pipeline.

[image]

I need to get the overall status (Success or Failed) of execute pipeline activity and pass it to stored procedure activity in the parameters.

I'm able to get the `datafactory` name, `pipelinename`. In the `pipelineStatus` im adding the below dynamic content

```
@activity('ExecutePipeline').output
```

My expected output is whether ExecutePipeline is "Succeeded" Or "Failed"

Please provide my the directions to achieve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass the expression `@activity('Execute Pipeline1').status` as the parameter of Stored procedure to return the status of `Execute pipeline activity`.

- You can connect the stored procedure activity **On completion** of execute pipeline.
  [image]
- In this demo, I used a set variable activity, and a variable is defined with the expression `@activity('Execute Pipeline1').status` in the activity.

[image]

**Output**
When execute pipeline activity is succeeded:
[image]

When execute pipeline activity is failed:
[image]

Comment: I think `Wait for completion` must be turned on for this to work properly.

Comment: Yes. `Wait for completion` is [turned on](https://i.imgur.com/XErbAHd.png)